# How to keep image within div container

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to edit images on a website. The issue I've noticed is that when I shrink the display to a small enough size, the images go outside of the div they are "in." How can I keep this from happening?

I've tried playing around with the positioning, adjusting the height/width, and changing the display preferences. `position: static` keeps the image from going outside of the div container, but the image now hovers above the bottom of the div.

```css
.team-member {
  background: $color_bg_grey;
  min-height: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.team-member img {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.team-member.ian {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%; 
}


.team-member.ian img {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
   <div class="team-member ian"><img class="photo_fit" 
        src="/img/team_photos/Angie.png" alt="Ian">
   </div>
 <h5>Angie Pope</h5>
  <p>Operations</p> 
</div>
```

I expect that the image would remain in the div container, but am instead seeing it either

- have its top go outside of the container,
- have it stay within the container, but instead float a decent amount of pixels above the bottom of the grey colored background.

[image: Outside of his container]
[image: Floating image]

Comment: give image `max-width: 100%`

Comment: She is still floating.

Comment: give me the whole code in form of codepen or fiddle, so i know exact problem

Comment: Found the solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: If the code does not work in future due to some any colour issues please add 
.team-member img {background: #F8F8F8;} by removing background: $color_bg_grey; inside team-member{...}. Hope this helps. The code may need improvement as it is bit oldskool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the object-fit property on the imgage:

```
.photo_fit {
  height: 320px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gh05d 's answer is useful, but it might stretch your image(which I assume you wouldn't want). You can use the following to avoid that.

```
div {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;    
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
div img {
    position:absolute;
}
```